# Output Array in a specific format

Tags: php

I have a php while loop as follows:

```
$tmp = array();
//loop for category dropdown menu
while($r = $stmt->fetch())        
{
$start_time = $r['consultation_start'];
$end_time = $r['consultation_end'];
$holiday = htmlspecialchars($r['consultation_holidays']);
$tmp[] =sprintf( " $holiday ," );     
}
//concatenate loop strings
foreach($tmp as $output)
{

$holidays =  implode('', $tmp);
$consultholidays = substr_replace($holidays ,"",-1);
}
echo $consultholidays;
$stmt->closeCursor(); 
}
```

I need to get the output in format:

```
[Sunday], [Wednesday]
```

I tried using:

```
$tmp[] =sprintf( " [$holiday] ," );
```

But it gives output as:

```
[Sunday,Wednesday]
```

How can i get the output format as:

```
[Sunday], [Wednesday]
```

Sorry, I am new to php and learning..so please forgive mistakes.

Comment: What does `$holiday` contains. Post its value.

Comment: @mega6382 $holiday contains  Sunday,Wednesday

Comment: this `[Sunday,Wednesday] ` don't define is it string or an array so be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$holiday = "Sunday,Wednesday";
$holidays = explode(",",$holiday);

$tmp[] = '['.implode('], [', $holidays).']'; 

var_dump($tmp);
```

**Or this:**

```
function surround($item)
{
    return "[" . ($item) . "],";
}
$holiday = "Sunday,Wednesday";
$holidays = explode(",",$holiday);
$str = implode(array_map('surround', $holidays));
$tmp[] = rtrim($str,','); 

var_dump($tmp);
```

The first uses only implode to glue the array together and separating them by `], [` and surrounding the entire string by `[` and `]`.

While the 2nd one uses `array_map` to surround individual item and then uses `implode` to turn them into string.

Comment: @ mega6382 array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "[Sunday], [Wednesday]" }

Comment: When using which solution 1st or second?

Comment: @Pamela make sure that you put the function `surround` outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank You so much for helping a newbie like me.

Answer (score 2):

as i thought if if $tmp is array and this `[Sunday], [Wednesday]` array too

so you can do like that

```
$tmp[] = [$holiday];
```

but if this is string like `'[Sunday], [Wednesday]'`

so try this

```
$tmp[] = $holiday;
echo '['.implode('], [', $tmp).']';
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ed43a880d62d71af0ffff62ac2e7ce604782404)

Comment: output is: [Sunday,Wednesday]

Comment: try this one `$tmp[] = $holiday; 
echo '['.implode('], [', $tmp).']';`